# data protection api

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

```
serviceCollection.AddDataProtection();
```

service collection does not contain definition. This is the error.

```
AddDataProtection();
```

I have added the correct packages for the console, still gives a error.

Below are the correct packages:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the dependences for IServiceCollection.

The below package needs to be installed error is solved.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.
ASP.NET Core logic to protect and unprotect data, similar to DPAPI.
```

Comment: Hi Master, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)